# Unity - Scriptable object automation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I have a requirement to automate the creation of X amount of scriptable objects from a CSV file, in the image below is an example of a manually completed one, the minimum amount of automation I need for this is the name/description/stat modifier.

The CSVtoSO class below successfully creates a SO with the name and description passed in as strings, the simple method that is called is in the base Inventoryitem class as below, the problem I have lies in the fact that I need to expose the class stat which is an enum and almost cast this as a string read in from the CSV

Ive dropped the statsEquippableItem Class at the bottom and within here I think I need an equivalent setter method but almost passing a string as the argument cast as the stats class which I dont think is possible, hopefully I have explained this post well enough, any tips would be great !

```
    public enum Stat
    {
        Mana,
        Stamina,
        Spirit,
        Intellect,
        Strength,
        Agility
    }
```

This method lives in InventoryItem

```
     public void SetDescription(string Description)

        {
            this.description = Description;
        }
```

[image: example of manual SO]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

public class CSVToSO 
{
    private static string EquipCSVLocation = "/Inventories/TestItemCSV.csv"; 
    [MenuItem("Utilities/generate equipment")]
    public static void GenerateEquip()
    {
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.dataPath + EquipCSVLocation); 

        foreach (string s in allLines)
        {
            string[] splitData = s.Split(',');

            

            StatsEquipableItem NewItem = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<StatsEquipableItem>();
            NewItem.SetDisplayName(splitData[0]); 
            NewItem.SetDescription(splitData[1]); 

            AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(NewItem,$"Assets/Game/EquippableItems/Resources/Rare/{NewItem.GetDisplayName()}.asset"); 
        }
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets(); 

    }
 
}
```

StatsEquipableItem Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

      public class StatsEquipableItem : EquipableItem, IModifierProvider
    {
        [SerializeField]
        Modifier[] additiveModifiers;
        [SerializeField]
        Modifier[] percentageModifiers;

        [System.Serializable]
        struct Modifier
        {
            public Stat stat;
            public float value;
        }   

        public IEnumerable<float> GetAdditiveModifiers(Stat stat)
        {
            foreach (var modifier in additiveModifiers)
            {
                if (modifier.stat == stat)
                {
                    yield return modifier.value;
                }
            }
        }


        public IEnumerable<float> GetPercentageModifiers(Stat stat)
        {
            foreach (var modifier in percentageModifiers)
            {
                if (modifier.stat == stat)
                {
                    yield return modifier.value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is "How do convert a string to an Enum value?".  If so, enum has the `Parse` and `TryParse` methods which take in a string and attempt to convert it to the enum value.

```
if (System.Enum.TryParse(statStringValue, out Stat statValue))
{
    Debug.Log($"Converted {statStringValue} to Stat value {statValue}");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log($"Unable to convert {statStringValue} to Stat value");
}
```